# Boolean column true and false vs true and null which is better?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When we need to store boolean fields in the database, which is better? true and null or true and false combination.

I have seen many article which says to use true and false. Some reports say true and null combinations provide better performance.

I am designing a website with Ruby on Rails and mariadb. I need to add a boolean status field to a table with 1 million rows.

The purpose of this status field is for filtering and reports.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Will there ever be `NULL`s in the fields or not?

Comment: If I am going to use true , false combination I would not allow null in column. If I need to use true , null instead of false, then there is going to be null instead of false. Which combination is better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL / MariaDB / InnoDB, `NULL` is indexed as if it were just another possible value.

What does matter...

- Use `NULL` for business logic, not performance.  For example: 'not yet answered', 'decline to state', 'N/A', 'not yet known' (eg `end_time`), 'do not care'.
- It is better to test for equality:  (`x = 0`, `x = false`, `x IS NULL`, `x = 1`, `x = true`) than for inequality.  (Some, not all, optimizations work better with equality tests.)
- As a rule, a single-column `INDEX` on a boolean quantity will never never be used.  The exception is when one of the values occurs very infrequently *and* you are testing for equal that value.
- On the other hand, it is quite fine to have a composite `INDEX` containing boolean column.  (Again, you need to test for equality, not inequality.)
- Even if you put the boolean first and it has poor selectivity, the Optimizer may be able to make very good use of the index.  In this extreme example, `INDEX(is_deleted, created_at)` makes it so that only 1 row needs to be looked at, regardless of table size or selectivity:

  ```
  WHERE is_deleted = false  -- Similarly:  deleted_date IS NULL
  ORDER BY created_at       -- ASC or DESC
  LIMIT 1
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Which is better?

> True and False
> True and **Don't Know**.

```
NULL != True
NULL != False
```

Also ...
NULL values are frequently *not included* in Indexes, so any kind of searching based on `WHERE .. IS NULL` is likely to run poorly.

> I need to add a boolean status field to a table with 1 million rows.

*On it's own*, a field that only ever has two values is a very *poor discriminator* and so an Index on this field *alone* may well be *discounted* by the Query Optimiser.  Instead, add this field onto your *existing* Indexes, to "qualify" your other ways of filtering the data.

Comment: The question is tagged mysql and mariadb, which both use InnoDB as their storage engine. InnoDB does include NULLs in indexes. `WHERE ... IS NULL` can use the index. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/is-null-optimization.html Though as you say, if it's not selective, the optimizer may skip using that index.